# Deleting MongoDB documents when any field name matches any item from a list of strings

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can I delete MongoDB documents which have fields that match any item from a given list of strings? For example, I want to remove the sub-documents having words ['Garbage', 'spam', 'useless'] from the following demo:

```
{
    _id: 24752893,
    dictionary: {
        word1: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        word2: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        word3: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        ....
    }
},
{
    _id: 6786765789,
    dictionary: {
        word1: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        word3: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        garbage: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        ....
    }
},
........
{
    _id: 76675567,
    dictionary: {
        spam: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        useless: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        word2: {
            language: ....,
            count: ....,
        },
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to keep the remaining words unchanged. I have seen many solutions to solve when field value matches any item from a list. Is there any way to match the field name with items from a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1**:

```js
let filter = ["garbage", "spam", "useless"];

db.dictionaris.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            dictionary: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: { $objectToArray: "$dictionary" },
                        as: "item",
                        cond: {
                            $not: [{ $in: ["$$item.k", filter] }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "dictionaris"
    }
]);
```

Note: [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/): Takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection. The $out operator must be the last stage in the pipeline.

**Solution #2**: For MongoDB version >= 4.4

```js
let filter = ["garbage", "spam", "useless"];

db.dictionaris.updateMany({},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                dictionary: {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: { $objectToArray: "$dictionary" },
                            as: "item",
                            cond: {
                                $not: [{ $in: ["$$item.k", filter] }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Test data:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 24752893,
    "dictionary" : {
        "word1" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word2" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word3" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        }
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 6786765789,
    "dictionary" : {
        "word1" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word3" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "garbage" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        }
    }
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 76675567,
    "dictionary" : {
        "spam" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "useless" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word2" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 24752893,
    "dictionary" : {
        "word1" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word2" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word3" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        }
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 6786765789,
    "dictionary" : {
        "word1" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        },
        "word3" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        }
    }
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 76675567,
    "dictionary" : {
        "word2" : {
            "language" : "Some word",
            "count" : "Some word"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the list or array of strings using an API like python's pymongo or java's MongoClient? Do I have to concatenate each string with "dictionary." in the front?

Comment: $out is creating a new collection, I don't want to do that. I want to update the same collection. Besides, it's taking a really long time.

Comment: I don't have any array field, if you look at the sample data you can see all of them are objects. So, $arrayToObject cannot be used. I feel like if I use $exists as true followed by an $unset, that could work. But I don't know how I can implement that with an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: I am converting `dictionary` object into array using `$objectToArray` first and then converting it back to object using `$arrayToObject`. Query should work. Try it. Check the updated answer with test data and output.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I had to change the variable name filter as this is a keyword in python3. And I had to put all of the operators and the fields inside quotations.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('Mongo-uri')
wl = ["garbage", "spam", "useless"]
client['db']['collection'].update_many(
    {},
    [
        {
            "$set": {
                "dictionary": {
                    "$arrayToObject": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$dictionary" },
                            "as": "item",
                            "cond": {
                                "$not": [{ "$in": ["$$item.k", wl] }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```